# RegisterClass error in Unity Editor when using Mono.WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, unity-game-engine, registerclass

I'm using `Mono.WinForms` to create external windows in Unity and it works great except that I get this error message each time I play the scene (but never the first time when Unity is freshly started):

> Could not register the window class, win32 error 0.

I figured that it was because that the form classes are not unregistered when I stop the scene. They do get unregistered when I restart Unity and I don't have the problem when I make a build, which makes sense.

I get this popup error twice and it's caused by:

1. `myForm = new Form1();`
2. `myForm.Show();`

I went through the code of the `XplatUIWin32.cs` file and found the `RegisterWindowClass` method. When Mono registers a class it does this:

```
class_name = string
         .Format("Mono.WinForms.{0}.{1}", 
           System.Threading.Thread.GetDomainID ().ToString (), classStyle);
```

So I managed to get rid of the second error by doing this:

```
UnregisterClass("Mono.WinForms.1.0", IntPtr.Zero);
```

So my question is why does it only work for the 2nd popup error and how do I get rid of the 1st one? I tried to force the garbage collection but it didn't help. I tried to find another registered class name but no luck here neither.

For info I use the mono version of System.Windows.Forms.dll as a reference, compile my code in Visual Studio and import the produced DLL in Unity. It works great apart from those popup errors.

Comment: I think the 2nd class is `SWFClass1` with `IntPtr.Zero` as a parent but it returns `False` when I try to unregister it even though the form is closed and disposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class_name = string.Format ("Mono.WinForms.{0}.{1}", System.Threading.Thread.GetDomainID ().ToString (), classStyle);
```

Two class name should be:

- Mono.WinForms.1.0
- Mono.WinForms.1.40

I use dnspy patch the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to see the `MessageBox` info with `class_name` shown.

I think the `classStyle` may not fixed, better try through different numbers.

BUT!!
I still get the messagebox shown with “Mono.WinForms.1.40” info